# Twitter client?

Tags: java, smartphone, twitter

I have a voice server which currently sends an email to notify when someone called.

But actually, since messages are very short ("[object] Name - number"), the server could just as well send a message with Twitter instead of forcing users to connect to their Gmail account (we don't use BlackBerry's, just smartphones with an unlimited Edge connection to the Net.)

I assume there are Java applets to connect to Twitter. Could someone recommend one?

FWIW, the phones are Nokia's and Samsung's (we might get some Android-based smartphones soon.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [JibJib](http://jibjib.org) it's a J2ME/JavaME Twitter client for cellphones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Posterous](http://www.posterous.com) to post twits using e-mail. BTW, my smartphone able to check GMail account periodically without third-party application.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should take a look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twitter_services_and_applications) on Wikipedia.

I personally use [Twibble](http://www.twibble.de/), which works fine.